Can get MongoDB collection infomation, but got Authentication failed error when using find() to get documents
I am able to use pymongo to get MongoDB collection list from a MongoDB 5.0 server, but got Authentication failed error when using find() to get documents from one of the collection.
import pymongo
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://username:password@hostname/?ssl=false&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=50000&connectTimeoutMS=10000&authSource=admin&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1")
mydb = myclient["mydatabase"]
mycol = mydb["customers"]
for x in mycol.find():
   print(x)

The error message is :
OperationFailure: Authentication failed., full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'Authentication failed.', 'code': 18, 'codeName': 'AuthenticationFailed', ......

Make sure that the account, you're using has the necessary permissions to read documents from the "customers" collection.

Yes, I can use that account to read documents from MongoDB Compass.

Try removing "ssl=false".
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://username:password@hostname/?serverSelectionTimeoutMS=50000&connectTimeoutMS=10000&authSource=admin&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1")


Currently, you're setting ssl to false in your connection string, ensure that SSL is indeed disabled on your MongoDB server. If SSL is enabled, you should set ssl to true in your connection string.
